# Запуск (git-)bash консоли из определенного местоположения

Tags: windows, bash

**Преамбула**: есть некоторое кол-во проектов, написанных с помощью разных технологий. Пишу программу, разворачивающую сразу всю среду разработки проекта, например: prj.sublime-project, prj.psd, prj.html, git-bash.

**Вопрос**: есть ли возможность вызвать bash-консоль из определенного местоположения?
Может, есть вариант передать параметры типа '--cd /d/folder'?
Или запустить sh-скрипт с возможностью(есть такая?) продолжить работу вручную после выполнения скрипта?

P.S. Помимо Git Bash Here в контекстном меню(Windows), т.е. интересует возможность именно автоматического вызова.
P.S.S. *Вариант вызова проекта из консоли алиасом - хорош, но не рассматривается.*

Comment: Непонятно, каким действием вы хотите запустить bash-консоль. Если кликом на ярлык, то установите в свойствах ярлыка начальную папку (и не забудьте убрать `--cd-to-home` из команды). Если из скрипта, то я полагаю, достаточно сделать `cd /папка/; bash.exe`.

Comment: ***рабочую папку**  
Спасибо, @Roman, то что нужно)